# Problem with passing information across Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I am trying to pass this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(ctx,SpendingsDetails.class);
extras.putString("SpendingAmount", "1");
extras.putString("SpendingDescription","2");
extras.putString("SpendingDate","3");
i.putExtras(extras);
startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

The activity that gets the information does the following information..

```
    spendingAmount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.spending_Sum);
spendingDetails=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.spending_Details);

Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null)
{
    spendingAmount.setText(extras.getString("SpendingAmount"));
    spendingDetails.setText(extras.getString("SpendingDescription"));
}
```

I am getting an error that the application cant continue on the first activities screen.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide on the error/logcat dump. And please elaborate on what you mean by "the application cant continue on the first activities screen"

Comment: it says the activity class cant be found.. do i have to put an activity xml into the manifest.xml for it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use like this

```
Intent i=new Intent(ctx,SpendingsDetails.class);
    i.putExtras("SpendingAmount", "1");
    i.putExtras("SpendingDescription","2");
    i.putExtras("SpendingDate","3");
    startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just call the getStringExtra directly:

```
spendingAmount.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("SpendingAmount"));
```

And so on for the other values you need.

Of course you could also do a check to see if the value exists first:

```
String spending = getIntent().getStringExtra("SpendingAmount");
if(spending != null) {
  spendingAmount.setText(spending);
}
```

EDIT: Like Rasel said:

```
i.putExtra("SpendingAmount", "1");
```

I didn't see that at first.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you declare extras? Look at the change.

```
Intent i=new Intent(ctx,SpendingsDetails.class);
Bundle extras=new Bundle();
extras.putString("SpendingAmount", "1");
extras.putString("SpendingDescription","2");
extras.putString("SpendingDate","3");
i.putExtras(extras);
startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you declared your bundle object. But does not allocate the memory. that is you need to add this code.

```
Intent i=new Intent(ctx,SpendingsDetails.class);
Bundle extras=new Bundle();// add this code and try once
extras.putString("SpendingAmount", "1");
extras.putString("SpendingDescription","2");
extras.putString("SpendingDate","3");
i.putExtras(extras);
startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please look into the LogCat for exception stack traces. Thats the first place to look when things "don't work".